# Alt+tab-ing games (like Trine or Aquaria)

Tags: games

Does anyone have any idea how to do the equivalent of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or to minimize games that take the mouse cursor?

I am using windowed mode.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-Alt-Arrows?

Comment: yes, but no luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> will release the mouse from the window, then you can minimize it or whatever from there.

Source: [Frozenbyte forum topic](http://frozenbyte.com/board/viewtopic.php?p=13605#p13605)

I am not sure if this is specific to the linux version of the Trine game, I will have to install Aquaria.  Love these Humble bundle games!

**EDIT:** Yes, works for Aquaria too.  Although, when you move the cursor over the window, it immediately recaptures it. whereas in Trine you have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to get back into the window.

Comment: This may be the only viable solution at the moment. When X allows an application to gain "exclusive mode," the window manager is not able to override. It's a long-known issue in X without any relevant fixes.

Comment: Can I ask where you get those shortcuts? I could not fine it using Google. Is there some place where there are all kind of these shortcuts?

Answer (score -1):

I've multiple virtual desktops (or workspaces, whatever they are called) and use the keyboard shortcuts to jump between these desktops.

Example:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> switches to Desktop1
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> switches to Desktop2
  With Hedgeward running on Desktop1 (not fullscreen), I press the keyboard for switching to Desktop2 and move the cursor to a place outside the game. After that, I switch back to Desktop1 in which I can minimize the game, open other windows, etc.

Other shortcuts I've tested:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>: open Kickoff menu
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>: run command

I must note that it only works with non-fullscreen applications.

Comment: It does not help. I don't know exacly, but there are more games that does not allow mouse exit, either do alt+tab. Mostly those games are proprietary